# Unity 2d script does not work when I clone the object

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, clone, instantiation

I have an object whith attached scrypt.

```
public GameObject scoreInfo;
static int CurrentScore = 0;

void OnMouseDown() //кнопка мыши нажата
{
    CurrentScore++;
    scoreInfo.GetComponent<Text>().text = CurrentScore.ToString();
}
```

I clone it in Unity 2d.

```
GameObject tmpObj = GameObject.Instantiate(spriteToDuplicate, WorldVector, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Inspector showes than this script attached to every clone and to real one ([Изображение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xj5R.png)), but when i click to the clone it does not work, but click to real one is work finley.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Please post in english or post here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: yea sorry I fix it.

Comment: Post the error that you're having problem with please

Comment: error:
When i click original object i got the result (incrementation of the score)
When i click clone object nothing works. (no one error in console)

Comment: Note that the gameobject that you click on needs some sort of collider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood. When cloning, the z axis was -10. Thays why click did not pass.

```
tmpObj.transform.position = new Vector3(tmpObj.transform.position.x, tmpObj.transform.position.y, 0);
```